# Console error while accessing property from object

Tags: javascript

Write a function called "addFullNameProperty".

Given an object that has a "firstName" property and a "lastName" property, "addFullNameProperty" returns a "fullName" property whose value is a string with the first name and last name separated by a space.

```
var person = {
  firstName: 'Jade',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};
addFullNameProperty(person);
console.log(person.fullName); // --> 'Jade Smith'
```

Starter Code:

```
function addFullNameProperty(obj) {
  // your code here
}
```

My code:

```
function addFullNameProperty(obj) {
  // your code here
  person.fullName = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
  return person.fullName;
}

var person = {
  firstName: 'Jade',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};
addFullNameProperty(person);
console.log(person.fullName); // --> 'Jade Smith'
```

I am getting a proper out as expected but while submitting work I am getting the below output.(might because some of the condition might not be satisfying)

[image: Here is an error]

The entire text from the error message is "should_create_a_fullName_property_with_the_firstName_and_lastName_separated_by_a_space"

Can someone please help me to find the condition?

Comment: `person` is not the function parameter. Your code only works because it's a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `obj` not `person` in your function, and then returning a string value -

```
function addFullNameProperty(obj) {
  // your code here
  var fullName = obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
  return fullName;
}

console.log(addFullNameProperty(person));
```

Answer (score 1):

`person` is not defined in the function.
should be:

```
function addFullNameProperty(obj) {
  // your code here
  obj.fullName = obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
  return obj.fullName;
}
```

Comment: Easy question, lots of the same answer at the same time :) but i was here first!

Comment: Correct - you were referencing the 'person' object directly.  I'm thinking that the testing system was simply trying to call your addFullNameProperty(obj) function, and didn't get the modified obj back.

Answer (score 0):

Update your function to use function parameter as follows -

```
function addFullNameProperty(obj) {
  // your code here
  obj.fullName = obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
  return obj.fullName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. Some one posted the same code in previous post.